# Is there any way to escape nameFilters in QDirIterator?

Tags: c++, qt

I have `[ThisIs] MyFile.zip` file in current directory. I have also following code:

```cpp
QDirIterator it("./", QStringList("[ThisIs] MyFile.zip"), QDir::Files);
bool has_next = it.hasNext();
```

Why has_next returns false? Probably because of square bracket chars in file name.
Is there any way to escape these characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name filters aren't documented anywhere. But its a reasonable guess that they work the same way as [QDir::setNameFilters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setNameFilters) which would mean they use [wildcard strings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#wildcardToRegularExpression).

The following should work:

```
QDirIterator it("./", QStringList("[[]ThisIs[]] MyFile.zip"), QDir::Files);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think a regex string will work. [wildcardToRegexExpression](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#wildcardToRegularExpression) will turn a glob/wildcard *into* a Regex pattern, but I don't think that means you can filter for specific characters such as your example. It's a shame there isn't more documentation for this, really.

Comment: @alteredinstance `wildcardToRegexExpression` states you can escape special characters by enclosing them in square brackets, the referenced man page also backs this up: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html

Comment: Yes, but does that mean the expression will work as a `nameFilter`? My thought is it won't since it states that it can only use wildcard patterns, and that `wildcardToRegexExpression` is used solely for wildcard matching with `QRegularExpression`, and not in this case

Comment: I presume as `QDir::setNameFilters`'s documentation references `wildcardToRegularExpression` that is the wildcard syntax that they support

Comment: Yep, it does: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/4cbadf699838406d14366ce61deec03cf45113f7/src/corelib/io/qdiriterator.cpp#L176

Comment: Nice find in the source code, I stand corrected. Even so, I don't think OP can escape the `[` in his example the way he needs to in order to make this work. Not certain though, I don't do much globbing

Comment: Yep, thats why I said "in theory", according to the docs it should work but I haven't tested it myself

Comment: I tried it using git bash on Windows - `ls '[[]ThisIs[]] MyFile.zip'` did not work - perhaps I'm doing it wrong though. It might also not support `[ ]` usage

Comment: @alteredinstance works without the quotes for me on Linux: `ls [[]ThisIs[]]\ MyFile.zip`, single quotes disable wildcards in bash

Comment: At least in bash escaping the closing bracket doesn't seem to be necessary: `ls [[]ThisIs]\ MyFile.zip` works too.

Comment: @AlanBirtles works! Thanks! I have read documentation but somehow skipped this: "Note: The backslash (\) character is not an escape char in this context. In order to match one of the special characters, place it in square brackets (for example, "[?]")."

Comment: @kungfu its not exactly the clearest documentation ever written (if you can find it at all)

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for a similar function [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setNameFilters) and some documentation on Qt's [wildcard matching](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#wildcard-matching)

> Each name filter is a wildcard (globbing) filter that understands * and ? wildcards.

Basically, you can't use the `filter` parameter in the way you are using it. You can do something like

```
QDirIterator it("./", QStringList("*.zip"), QDir::Files);
```

And from there, check each file for your specified name `"[ThisIs] MyFile.zip"`. But using filters to do anything other than wildcard expressions is invalid in Qt.

Comment: Do you know that file names can contain characters like '?' or '*'? You are wrong: "But using filters to do anything other than wildcard expressions is invalid in Qt."

Comment: @kungfu Yes, "?" symbols are part of the valid glob expression syntax. The function you are using is only capable of wildcard/globbing. The way you are doing it does not work.

Comment: I know what name filters are for. My question was how to escape globbing characters and I have add '[ThisIs] MyFile.zip' name only for simplicity. In real I will use `[[]ThisIs[]]My[*]File.part*.rar` nameFilter for such files as `[ThisIs]*MyFile.part01.rar`, `[ThisIs]*MyFile.part02.rar`